# Cauchy problem for convolution operators

Tags: differential-equations

I don't know how to solve the following Cauchy problem:

$$f'(x)=-x f\ast g(x) \qquad \text{ and }\quad f(0)=1. $$

Could you please help me with this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: With what (assumptions) about $g$ and in what class of $f$'s?

Comment: $g\in C^{\infty}_c$

Comment: Could you please put parentheses in the formula $xf\star g$, and specify the domain of $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your equation means $f'=-(xf)\star g$, and that convolution in the Laplace convolution, apply Laplace transform to both sides, and formally obtain
$$zF-1=-F'G,$$
so
$$F=\frac{1}{I}\int (I/G)dz,$$
where
$$I=\exp\left(\int (z/G)dz\right).$$
The complete justification of these formulas depends on your exact assumptions about $g$, and the class of functions $f$ where you look for a solution.

Comment: The OP has specified the class of $g$. Let's assume we just want $f\in C^1(\mathbb R)$. Then what use is this approach?

Comment: @fedja: they did not specify many other things: a) Is RHS $(xf)\star g$ or $x(f\star g)$, b) what is the domain of $x$? Is this a Laplace convolution or convolution on $R$? When all this will be settled I can think about the problem.

Comment: Agreed, the question was asked badly. OK, let's ignore it until a clarification is made.